# Accessing JavaScript '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app running on node/express. I am tripping myself up it seems with `[object Object]`.

I render a page like so

```
app.get('/members', checkAuthentication, function(req, res){
  res.render('members', { user: req.user });
});
```

To access the user email on my page (.ejs) I can just do

```
<%= user.email %>
```

I have some client side logic then where I want to pass the users email address to the server for a particular process. Again quite simple

```
body: JSON.stringify({user_email: "<%= user.email %>", token: token})
```

Server side

```
app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.user_email)
  //'myEmailAddress@domain.com'
}
```

The part where I am tripping myself up it seems is if I want to pass the whole user object across

```
body: JSON.stringify({user: "<%= user %>", token: token})
```

Server Side

```
app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.user)
  //'[object Object]'
}
```

How do i access the users email now for example?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you simply write `JSON.stringify(user)` ?

Comment: yes agree with @MichaelBeeson

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure are you using `body-parser` or not.
Add this package in `app.js`(assuming)

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

and before routes add this line,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

EDIT :

```
app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(req.body.user))
}
```

Comment: Please check EDIT

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: means data is not coming a json. check request payload in xhr tab of network and check its there ?

Comment: Ah right, it's being sent as `user: "[object Object]"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what `req.body.user` contains/looks like try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.user))
```

Comment: Hi, this returns `"[object Object]"`